# Mix.Shell.cmd error when upgraded to elixir 1.6.1

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

My code was working fine on elixir `1.5.2` and then I upgraded to elixir `1.6.1`. It gave me `Mix.Shell.cmd/2` is undefined or private error. This is the code

```
   def run(args) do
     file = List.first(args) || "priv/static/apiv1docs.json"
     Mix.Shell.cmd("rm -rf " <> file, &IO.puts(&1))
     IO.puts("Removed " <> file)
   end
```

It gave me error.`Mix.Shell.cmd/2` is undefined or private error. Did you mean one of `cmd/3`.

It was working fine before on `1.5.2`.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mix.Shell.cmd takes 3 arguments:

> `cmd(command, options, callback)`

You can pass an empty list as a second argument to use default options.

[You can see the docs here](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Shell.html#cmd/3)

In 1.5.2 the function definition had `[]` as a default value for options:

> `cmd(command, options \\ [], callback)`

. I'm not sure why they changed it

[Mix.Shell.cmd/3 v1.5.2](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.5.2/Mix.Shell.html#cmd/3)

Comment: I would report it as an issue; there were no depreciation warning, it should be backwards compatible.